# Algorithm not showing right output

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array, 2d

**The Question was:**

You are given a binary matrix (i.e. each element of matrix is either 0 or 1) of size n × n. You want to re-arrange 1's in such a way that they form a rectangular region. Note that the rectangular region should be made of only 1's, and all the 1's of the entire matrix should be in this rectangular region.

For achieving rectangular region, you can swap any two elements of the matrix. Please find out the minimum number of swaps needed. If it is not possible to re-arrange 1's in the desired way, please print -1.

**Input**

First line of the input contains a single integer T denoting number of test cases.
Description of T test cases follows.
First line of each test case will contain a single integer n denoting dimension of matrix.
Each of next n lines will contain n space separated integers denoting the ith row of the matrix.

**Output**

For each test case, print a single line containing a single integer denoting minimum number of swaps needed or -1 depending on the situation.

**Example**

Input:

```
2

2

0 1

1 0

2

1 1 

1 0
```

Output:

```
1 

-1
```

**Explanation**

Example case 1. You can swap 1 of second row first column with 0 of first row first column. 
After the swap, matrix will look as follows.

```
1 1 
0 0
```

Here all the 1's form a rectangular region of dimension 1 × 2. In this case, 1 swap will be needed.

Note that you can also swap 1 at first row second column with 0 at second row second column too.
Matrix after this swap will be following.

```
0 0
1 1
```

So you need 1 swap in this case too.

So overall, you need 1 swap.

Example case 2. There is no way to create a rectangular region containing 3 1's in a matrix of dimension 2 × 2, hence answer is -1.

**My Algorithm [Edit]**

1. First i am Taking Number of Cases from user
2. Then the order of matrix [will be of nxn order].
3. So logic is that if matrix is 1x1 then it will simply print 0
4. else while taking input from user [that will be only 1 or 0] i am counting 1's because the logic i develop that when in a matrix of odd order the 1's will be even then it cannot be arranged in rectangular form.and for even order of matrix if 1's are odd , not arrange able .
5. Next i am traversing each index if i find one then i move to next element else i try to find 1 in the same colomn if dont find than i am breaking loop showing -1 that it is not arrange able in rectangular form
6. Than after arranging a row i check the next row whether it is already arranged or not if it is than i break everything and moves to next case

n rectangular form

**My Solution**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

    static long startTime;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int numberOfOnes = 0;
            int T = scanner.nextInt();

            for (int t = 1; t <= T; t++) {
                int n = scanner.nextInt();

                int loopCounter, swapCounter = 0;
                boolean rowContainsZero = false;
                int array[][] = new int[n][n];
                boolean reject = true;
                //Worst and the most simpler conditions
                if (n == 1) {
                    System.out.print("0");
                    exitingSystem();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        array[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
                        if (array[i][j] == 1) {
                            numberOfOnes++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (n % 2 == 0 && numberOfOnes % 2 != 0) {
                    System.out.println("-1");
                    if (t == T) {
                        exitingSystem();
                    }
                    continue;

                } else if (n % 2 != 0 && numberOfOnes % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("-1");
                    if (t == T) {
                        exitingSystem();
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                //     System.out.println("Here i am");
                //From here swaping processes will take the place
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        if (array[i][j] == 1) {
                            continue;
                        } else if (array[i][j] == 0) {
                            loopCounter = i;
                            reject = true;
                            while (loopCounter < n) {
                                if (array[loopCounter][j] == 1) {
                                    int temp = array[loopCounter][j];
                                    array[loopCounter][j] = array[i][j];
                                    array[i][j] = temp;
                                    reject = false;
                                    swapCounter += 1;
                                    break;
                                }
                                loopCounter++;
                            }
                             if (rowContainsZero) {
                                System.out.println("" + swapCounter);
                                    break;
                            }
                            if (reject == true) {
                                System.out.println("-1");
                                break;
                            } else {
                                for (int m = i + 1; m < n; m++) {
                                    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                                        if (array[m][k] == 0) {
                                            rowContainsZero = true;
                                        } else {
                                            rowContainsZero = false;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            System.out.println("0's and 1's were Expected :(");
                            exitingSystem();
                        }
                    }
                    if (reject == true) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

    }

    public static void exitingSystem() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

**BUT THE CODECHEF COMPUTER SAYING WRONG ANSWER + They allowed to take input from keyboard too**

Comment: Please explain your algorithm. First, people often find their mistake when they try to explain their reasoning to someone else. Second, it makes it easier for us to find a problem. Reverse-engineering such a long method isn't easy.

Comment: should i explain in an edit or in comment?

Comment: Better edit your question.

Comment: i tried to explain everything and edited

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That helps a lot.

Comment: is it ok if you print like this 1 0 0 1 instead of 0 1 1 0?

Comment: you have to print the number of swaps if it is arrangable to rectangular form

Comment: like if have matrix {{1 1 1 0},{0,0,0,1},{1,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1}} thn i hv to tell how many swaps it will need to be like {{1 1 1 1},{1,1,1,1},{0 0 0 0},{0,0,0,0}} if it is not possible than it should print -1

Answer (score 0):

I think your algorithm isn't fully correct.

I think the following is a counter-example for your step 4 / odd order (n=3) and even number of ones (numberOfOnes=4):

```
1 1 0
1 1 0
0 0 0
```

This should give 0.
Similar for n=4 and numberOfOnes=3:

```
1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

This should give 0 as well.

I haven't yet deeply analyzed your steps 5 and 6.

Here are some more examples:

```
1 1 1 0
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 0 0
```

This should give -1, as from 10 ones you can only form rectangles of the form 2*5 or 1*10, which both don't fit into the 4*4 frame.

```
1 1 1 0
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
1 0 0 0
```

This should give 1, as by moving the lower-left 1 two palces up and right, you get a 3*3 rectangle.

Comment: if this passes this then on the next steps where i commented like  //From here swaping processes will take the place will deal with this all and qill find ut if this can form ractangle

Comment: Sorry, I looked mainly at the algorithm explanation, not so much into your code. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way you are trying to solve problem. Suppose you have

```
                                                                 0 0 1
                                                                 0 1 1
                                                                 0 0 1
```

This is a perfect example of solveable matrix but you can't simply use random swap and then acquire result. You need to use `A*` search algorithm with manhatten distance.

- Make a priority queue
- Define manhatten distance.
- Create a function which creates succesors of each board. Like if i have above board then it will give you a collection of boards back:

  `0 0 1 
   0 1 1 ==> colection
   0 0 1`

  `0 1 1
   0 0 1
   0 0 1`

  `0 0 1
   0 0 1
   0 1 1`

  `0 1 0
   0 1 1
   0 0 1`

  `0 0 1
   0 1 1
   0 1 0`
- Description of A:*
- an initial lis to store visited boar so that you don't visit them again.
- `i will call MinPriority queue a pq`
- `insert the initial_board in pq
- while(!pq.isEmpty() && !foundGoal(pq.min)) //You find goal when your
  manhatten distance is 0.
- board = pq.delMin(); //you have to override the distance method in
  priority queue so it will return you that board whoms manhatten
  distance is smallest.
- for(boards b :board.getSuccesors(); // give you collection of boards.
- if(notvisited(b,vistiedList)) // so that you don't come in same state again and
  again.
- pq.insert(b);
  visitedList.add(b);`

In first year i had to solve 8-puzzle and you can solve this way however you can also use hamming distance but that's not efficient and here [is 8-puzzle](https://github.com/afrazsalim/Gegevens-en-algorithm/tree/master/8-Puzzle-solver/gna-practicum2-2014-2015/gna-practicum2-2014-2015/src/gna) code(with A* implementation).